# When are my kids old enough to mow the lawn?

Tags: safety, chores

I'm sure this largely has to do with personality (well behaved, cautious) as it does age, but what is an appropriate age for kids to start using a push lawn mower? Or a riding mower?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We had to go by size and strength rather than age. Our oldest is small for her age, so she and her sister started together. I went by "big enough to push the lawn mower and smart enough not to stick their hands underneath." That turned out to be 12 for the oldest and 10 1/2 for the second. Our third started when he was 10, but mainly because he wanted in on [bidding for the job](http://rabidpaladin.com/post/2008/10/04/Capitalist-Experiment.aspx)...

Comment: The bidding reminds me of Cheaper by the Dozen. Tremendously entertaining book.

Answer (score 3):

I rode my grandpas riding mower at nine or ten. The problem was more a question of not being able to actually do the job than safety at that point, meaning my grandpa had to go out and do it again to get the spots I missed.

So, fun, but hardly useful at that age.

I did, usefully but not enjoyably, mow my parents lawn with a [manual mower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aReelMower.png) at about the same age too.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly depends on how mature the child is, not how old they are.

Comment: While I agree with you, this isn't a particularly helpful answer.  If you believe maturity is more relevant than age, then your answer should include some way of identifying if a child is mature enough.  As it is now, your response is more along the lines of "you asked the wrong question", rather than a useful answer.